# How do I draw a graph in my application?

Tags: java, android, android-graphview

I need to incorporate a graph into my android application, I am trying to follow this tutorial:

http://www.jjoe64.com/2011/07/chart-and-graph-library-for-android.html

I tried putting it into my activity class and it shows up with a ton of errors related to `GraphView`. Here are the snippets of code:

```
// graph with dynamically genereated horizontal and vertical labels   
GraphView graphView = new GraphView(   
  this // context   
  , new GraphViewData[] {   
    new GraphViewData(1, 2.0d)   
    , new GraphViewData(2, 1.5d)   
    , new GraphViewData(2.5, 3.0d) // another frequency   
    , new GraphViewData(3, 2.5d)   
    , new GraphViewData(4, 1.0d)   
    , new GraphViewData(5, 3.0d)   
  } // data   
  , "GraphViewDemo" // heading   
  , null // dynamic labels   
  , null // dynamic labels   
);   
LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.graph1);   
layout.addView(graphView);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are supposed to put it in your onCreate method of your activity after you call setContentView method.

Answer (score 0):

This library has issues, because there is no Javadoc and you have to figure out how to use it by reading the source code. You may get compile errors relating to GraphViewData, because you are supposed to explicitly import this class embedded within the GraphView class:

```
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView.GraphViewData;
```

You also cannot have a black text, white background colour scheme without "hacking the source code". It assumes you need only light text, black background graphs.

Answer (score 0):

You should use AchartEngine[AchartEngine](http://www.achartengine.org)

its good for making any type of chart and graphs in android..it may be helpful to you...!